# macOS - Jenkins - ssh - xccode - Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain

Tags: macos, jenkins

**Symtom Description**

When SSH'ed into a mac running 10.15.1 (Catalina) (or connected via Jenkins using a node that connects via ssh), if I try to build my xcode project (building an iOS mobile app), the codesigning phase fails with the error:

`Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'myproj' from project 'myproj')`

in several places (always around when I am calling codesign)

**What I have tried**

Originally the issue I was having was that I was receiving an "errSecInternalComponent" and the build was failing.

I tried adding calls to explicitly unlock the login keychain (security unlock-keychain) where my signing certs were located and that helped that issue, but the Operation not permitted message persisted.

I confirmed that building directly from the command line on the mac itself in a terminal window works just fine. This problem is exclusive to connections via ssh

I updated System Preferences --> Privacy & Settings --> Developer Tools to include allowing every program I could think of that might be related (including all xcode tools, codesign, java, and several others I thought could be related to anything Jenkins might try to do), but this alone didn't make a difference

I tried creating a new mac node in Jenkins that connected via JNLP instead to see if that helped, but got the same result.

I disabled csrutil from the OS Recovery partition but this did not help.

I moved my certs to the System keychain to see if that helped. It didn't.

This build runs fine on the older mac mini (pre-T2 security chip), but this new machine is a newer mac-mini with the T2 chip. Just to rule out everything, I even dropped the security level on safe boot, but that had no impact.

The older machine is also not running Catalina.

Anyone else ever hit this? And if so, did you figure it out?

Comment: I see the same messages on jenkins via ssh -- my xcodebuild run was printing BUILD SUCCEEDED but returning with exit code 65. I thought it was due to same error you've got, except builtin-RegisterExecutionPolicyException preceding it, just after code sign step. Turned out to be something else failing earlier in my build. After fixing that, I still get the same error but xcodebuild returns okay error code. So worth making sure it actually isn't something else failing your build!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response -- I did hit this issue, and the thing that fixed it was passing `UseModernBuildSystem=NO`...?!

EDIT: I also spent a lot of time messing around with the Jenkins shell invocation. I know that if I login to the machine (physically), that my build command (via fastlane) worked. I might've also used the login bash shell to call it as well.

In my jenkinsfile, I have something like this:

```
def loginShell(cmd) {
    sh """#!/bin/zsh --login
    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    ${cmd}
    """
}
```

all my lanes call through this when invoking fastlane commands (i.e. `xcodebuild` under the hood).

The one thing I didn't have much luck with is actually figuring out if `zsh` had a `--login` param. I know `bash` does - so if it doesn't work for you, change your shebang to bash ;)

It seemed to find all my `$PATH` garbage so I guess it worked.